# Add label while program running PyQt

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, qt-designer

I have just started to use Qt Designer for python, I designed a main window. I want to add a label when the button clicked.I found anserwers that says to use layout, but it doesnt seems that Qt Designer using it. Im trying this:

```
from main_ui import *
import sys
def send():
        label=QtGui.QLabel(myapp.ui.centralwidget)
        label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 46, 13))
        label.setText(myapp.ui.lineEdit.text())


try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myapp = StartQT4()
myapp.show()
QtCore.QObject.connect(myapp.ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), send)

QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(myapp)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and it does nothing.I want to add a label and I cant find how to do that, please if somone can help me I would be thankful. my ui file is:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import time

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)
class StartQT4(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(767, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 300, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 330, 371, 71))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 767, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 70, 301, 191))
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("scrollArea"))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 299, 189))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("scrollAreaWidgetContents"))
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        p= QtGui.QPalette()
        p.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Background, QtCore.Qt.white)
        self.scrollArea.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.scrollArea.setPalette(p)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "send", None))
```

Comment: Have you tried to call `label.show()` after adding it?

Comment: Wow! I have tried it before and it somehow didn't work, and it do now! Thank you very much.

Comment: Widgets are shown with their parent if they are created before the parent is shown itself. Afterwards you need to manually call show. This allows you to create widgets and show them on demand.
Not sure what you meant with designer not using layouts as that is what one usually does with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the label in your GUI description:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import time

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)
class StartQT4(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(767, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 300, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 330, 371, 71))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))

        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 400, 371, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("color:rgb(255, 85, 127)"))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))


        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 767, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 70, 301, 191))
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("scrollArea"))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 299, 189))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("scrollAreaWidgetContents"))
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        p= QtGui.QPalette()
        p.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Background, QtCore.Qt.white)
        self.scrollArea.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.scrollArea.setPalette(p)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "send", None))
```

Afterwards set a text to this label in your **def send(self):** (supposed your GUI-file is named "GUI.py":

```
from GUI import Ui_MainWindow
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s


class MAIN(Ui_MainWindow):
    def send(self):
        print ui.lineEdit.text()
        ui.label.setText(ui.lineEdit.text())
        app.processEvents()


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
Dialog = QtGui.QMainWindow()
ui = MAIN()
ui.setupUi(Dialog)
print dir(Dialog)

QtCore.QObject.connect(ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), ui.send)

QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

Dialog.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```